# Kubernetes connection error in Mac

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

OS : OSX (mac)

Docker : 18.06.0-ce (edge)

Kubernetes : 1.10.3

I use Kubernetes for the first time.

I tried Google but could not find the manual for Kubernetes, which operates on the Mac.

Running `kubectl version` outputs `The connection to the 
server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

Comment: Kubernetes proper has a lot of documentation at https://kubernetes.io/.  The Docker for Mac Kubernetes documentation is at https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/kubernetes/.

Comment: The error I mentioned is not mentioned.

Comment: How did you install/deploy k8s?

Comment: P.S: k8s is a short form of kubernetes

Comment: Google “kubectl connection refused mac”, you’re not the first with the issue and after a quick look it might be one of several reasons why you get this error.

Comment: Provide information how you installed kubernetes.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this issue when changing from minikube to the Docker Desktop supplied Kubernetes. For me, the issue was caused by a stale .kube configuration. Posting my workaround here as this was the first result I found on google when looking to troubleshoot the issue.

#### 1. Uninstall Minikube

I had originally installed with homebrew: `brew uninstall minikube`. If installed using other methods, go back to your install source for uninstall info.

After minikube was uninstalled, I restarted my machine which may or may not have been necessary but it is what I did.

#### 2. Disable Kubernetes in docker Desktop

1. Open Docker Desktop preferences, click Kubernetes menu
2. De-select 'Enable Kubernetes' checkbox. Click Apply & Restart

#### 3. Remove old kube and minikube config

1. Open terminal to your home directory.
2. Check for settings directories: `ls -al` and look for `.kube` and `.minikube`.
3. Remove `.kube` settings: `rm -rf ./.kube`.
4. Remove `.minikube` settings: `rm -rf ./.minikube`.
5. Confirm: `ls -al` and make sure the `.kube` and `.minikube` directories have been deleted.
6. If everything looks good, close terminal.

#### 4. Re-enable Kubernetes in Docker Desktop

1. Open Docker Desktop preferences, click Kubernetes menu
2. Select 'Enable Kubernetes' checkbox. Click Apply & Restart
3. Open new terminal window and run `kubectl version`. You should see info for Client Version and Server Version if everything worked.

Comment: This is the only solution worked

Answer (score 2):

When you run `kubectl`, the `.kube/config` file is read in your home directory, thus telling which cluster you want to connect to using `--context=<cluster-name>`

What your error output is telling you is that it is unable to find a listening `kubernetes` API endpoint upon which to run those commands. It is looking for a cluster at `localhost:8080`

This endpoint will vary depending on how and where you installed Kubernetes. How are you running Kubernetes?

Are you using the bundled **Docker/Kubernetes for Mac** as mentioned here? - [Docker for Mac Kubernetes](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/kubernetes/) or are you using a tool like **MiniKube?** - [MiniKube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)

Answer (score 1):

You might notice this error `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` because of your local **minikube server might be down**.

You have to start the existing minikube instance using - **minikube start** (I'm assuming your local minikube configured with docker driver earlier like:  `minikube start --driver=docker`)

If not working above step then you have to delete the existing minikube then start it again:

```bash
minikube delete
minikube start --driver=docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and my user id  did not had the admin privileges, once the chown is done, Kubernetes started working.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For my part, Kubernetes was not enabled within Docker Desktop.
Here's how to enable Kubernetes on Mac:

1. Click on settings on top right
2. Click on "Kubernetes"
3. Check "Enable Kubernetes"

[image]